Нужен батник с копированием файла с сервера
Нужно создать батник так чтобы после запуска батника:

из сервера на пк в определенную папку копируются 2 файла
после этого проверяется разрядность ОС
и после определения разрядности запускается файл скачанный с сервера
и конец

я не могу разобраться то одно то другое каждый раз не работает

попробуйте декомпозировать поставленную перед вами сложную комплексную задачу на отдельные под-задачи.

по сути то тут только 3 задания идет

копирование 2 файлов
определение разрядности
запуск файла
тут батника мне кажется одного хватит чтобы это все выполнить


Нехватает сведений об операционной системе.

Windows 8.1,10. Но большинство 10. Задача такая , чтобы скачать 2 файла реестра с сервера , и после определения разрядности ОС активировался реестр под ос и все

Если без 7, то можно повершель

я бы конечно сделал , если бы умел. не умею вот в чем проблема. Был бы благодарен если бы кто то скинул готовое , в коде чутка понимаю там бы уже под свои ссылки поменял и сделал.

https://pikabu.ru/story/otvet_na_post_u_kogo_snova_raspidorasilo_yutub_na_pk_11685586 вот тут что то про батники с архитектурой

С помощью PowerShell (*.ps)
Копирование файлов и каталогов
Чтобы скопировать один файл 1.txt из каталога C:\SourceFolder\ в F:\DestFolder, выполните:
Copy-Item -Path "C:\SourceFolder\1.txt" -Destination "F:\DestFolder\1.txt"

Можно использовать сокращенный синтаксис командлета, пропустив указание параметров Path и Destination:
cpi "C:\SourceFolder\1.txt" "F:\DestFolder\1.txt"

Как узнать разрядность Windows с помощью PowerShell
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth

--> 
64 (или 32) 

Everything you wanted to know about the if statement
$value = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth
if ( $value -match '64')
{
    # do something
}

Запустить процесс
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c dir `"%SystemDrive%\Program Files`""

или просто имя файла (параметры опционально), если дополнительно ничего не требуется.
Итого:
mybat.ps
cpi "\\server\SourceFolder\*.exe" "X:\DestFolder\"
if ( (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth -match '64')
{
    X:\DestFolder\myexe64.exe
}
else
{
    X:\DestFolder\myexe32.exe
}


а если bat файл сделать? сможете помочь с кодом и обьяснить что и как за что отвечает?

В бате сходу и не скажу, как добыть разрядность процессора. А чем powershell не нравится? То же самое, практически. В ответе есть все необходимые команды.

я не умею powershell.ом пользоваться , если поможешь полностью с файлом , почитал бы посмотрел что и как , а так вообще 0 в нем

Это не должно вас останавливать.

было бы интересно да новому обучиться , но я больше в разработки в СЭД Directum RX , а тут больше для спокойной работоспособности своей

Ну так и обучайтесь! Или вас лень сдерживает? Появилась задача - нужно решить (самостоятельно). Информации в Интернете полно. Обычно, я решаю практически любую задачу максисмум за день.

желание бешенное , а вот возможности грубо говоря нет

Алгоритм, кстати, нужно поменять: 1) проверяется разрядность ОС; 2) из сервера на пк в определенную папку копируется нужный файл; 3) файл запускается.
